# printf thousand separator not working on MacBook

Tags: printf

I am using the following command on Terminal in MacBook.

```
printf "The number is %'d\n" 123456
```

I expect the output:

> The number is 123,456.

But I am getting:

> The number is 123456.

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: While on first glance it looks like a duplicate, this question is actually asking why the printf answer doesn't work for him/her.

Comment: It works for me on macOS 10.11.6.  What country are you in (and what language did you set your computer to during installation)?  Edit into the question.

Answer (score 3):

> Please point out my mistake.

I guess you mean this:

```
printf "%'.3d\n" 123456
123,456
```

Bear in mind that the separator depends on your `locale`.

```
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
printf "%'.3d\n" 123456
123,456

LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
printf "%'.3d\n" 123456
123 456
```

There is a good description available **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374868/number-formatting-in-bash-with-thousand-separator#9375024)**.